# Typescript: where is the body of this function defined and are the generics really used?

Tags: angular, typescript

I was having a look at the documentation of [Angular's "AsyncPipe"](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe?fbclid=IwAR2t-aJAA3n4pcyhQsthsl7he6VqkmAokaLqs8a5rBl4xuMhIqnm5LQUaVg) and I got kind of stuck in line 26, where the '*resolve*' function is called: `this.resolve !('hi there!');`

Could anyone answer the following questions:

- (A) Where is the body of the function defined? I tried the code and played a bit around, changing the type and amount of parameters, for example: `resolve(1, 'hello', true)`, or `resolve(1)`, or `resolve()`. In every case, the value of the FIRST parameter was returned (it was an empty output in the last case), but I do not see anywhere such a function definition.
- (B) I see that in line 19 the `Promise` is defined with `<string>`. Nonetheless, as shown in (A), I was able to pass and return strings, numbers, booleans... perhaps I misunderstood what this typing is suposed to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I went ahead and answered the question as well, but `resolve` is a very common word in JavaScript related to promises, an asynchronous way of handling code in JavaScript without using callbacks. It seems that learning about `Promises` would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to address here:

(A) `resolve` is a specific function to `Promises` along with the function `reject`. They are your asynchronous functions to determine what to do with the result (`resolve`) or the error (`reject`). The `resolve` function returns the first parameter and nothing else, if you need to return more than one value it can be done in an object.

(B) Typescript only exists in the IDE/code editor, not at runtime. Typescript at runtime is transpiled down to JavaScript and a lot of the functionality (generics included) are lost in the browser. The generics are there to help you when developing your code so you don't run a Number function on a String, or some similar idea. So when you get to running the Angular application you'll be able to send in anything you want, but in development your IDE should warn you if the types mismatch (especially if you are using `tslint` with your development tools)

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the answer. It's hard to know where to look for when you have so many concepts overlapping. I guess people could have just adressed me into the right direction instead of just down-voting. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

The `this.resolve` function is assigned at line 19:

```
this.greeting = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => { this.resolve = resolve; });
```

The `Promise<string>` only defines the variable `resolve` should accept a string argument (i.e. `resolve: (string) => void`).

`this.resolve` is defined in line 13:

```
private resolve: Function|null = null;
```

Because it is defined with type `Function|null`, it does not restrict on the number of arguments it should be called with nor the type of those arguments.

It is referenced with `!` (in `this.resolve!(...)`) because its type has `null` in it, and the `!` tells the compiler that the value is not `null` or `undefined` at that moment.

The example is not that well written.
It could be improved like this:

```
export class AsyncPromisePipeComponent {
  greeting: Promise<string>;
  arrived: boolean = false;

  private resolve: (string) => void;

  constructor() { this.reset(); }

  reset() {
    this.arrived = false;
    this.greeting = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => { this.resolve = resolve; });
  }

  clicked() {
    if (this.arrived) {
      this.reset();
    } else {
      this.resolve('hi there!');
      this.arrived = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The changes are:

- removing the `null` and `null` initialization:

  - there is no reason to initialize the value with `null`,
  - the constructor calls `this.reset()` which set those properties immediately. So they will not be null.
  - always use `undefined` if you really need to (JavaScript should not have two bottom values to begin with).
  - now you can skip the `!` in `this.resolve!()`
- `private resolve: (string) => void`:

  - always be specific when possible.